# How to integrate Swiper and Laravel using Laravel Mix

Tags: css, laravel, buttonclick, laravel-mix, swiper.js

I don't know whether this is allowed or not but I have a two-part question. How can I integrate swiper.js and swiper.min.css with Laravel? I'm using Laravel Mix to compile JS and SASS files. My second question is, how can I call an "onClick" event function in Laravel? I'm using Laravel 7.3.1.

**app.js**

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    effect: 'coverflow',
    grabCursor: 'true',
    centeredSlides: 'true',
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    coverflowEffect: {
        rotate: 50,
        stretch: 0,
        depth: 100,
        modifier: 1,
        slideShadows: true,
    },
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
    },
});
```

**Blade**

```
{{ asset('public/js/app.js') }}
{{ asset('public/css/swiper.min.css' )}}
```

For the second part of the question – I want to call the following function in my Blade/view.

```js
function close() {
    document.getElementByClassName("media-icons").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementByID("hide-icon-panel").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementByID("show-icon-panel").style.display = "inline-block";
}
```

Included the function in my Blade like in the following way:

```
<button id="hide-icons" onclick="w3_close();"><i class="left"></i>. 
</button>
```

I tried all of the above and nothing seems to work. Please help, your assistance will be very much helpful.

Answer (score -1):

```
import Swiper from './swiper.min.js'
const swiper = new Swiper(...)
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow, please explain your code, so the OP can understand it easier.

Comment: This answer doesn't fix the problem with integrating laravel mix and swiperjs.